# How are ephemeral host ports useful when using docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports) of ports section in docker compose file, when we omit the host port, it will be chosen **randomly**. For example:

```
ports:
  - "80" # container port: 80, host port: ephemeral(random)
```

How is this useful? How is this feature being used in practice?

Answer (score 3):

The term "ephemeral" is usually defined as an attribute for something, that has a short lifespan.  Here it means, that every time you restart the container, it will be mapped to another "random" host port. It usually is a very high port number, larger than 60000. I can see three use cases, where this behaviour can be beneficial:

- It assures that there will be no port conflicts with other services
  already running on the host. Let's say there is an Apache service
  running on port 80, starting an nginx container with single port
  syntax "80", won't throw an error. This can simplify testing. You
  can quickly test a service, without having to stop the other one,
  that occupies the port.
- It can also be utilized as some form of security feature. When open
  host ports change periodically in a random fashion, it will    be
  harder    to penetrate a system.
- I believe, the use cases it is actually meant for, are stack deployments of multiple
  instances that use the same internal container ports. To find out the actual ports after deployment, you can run a script, which checks each instance using "docker inspect" and feed that info to other dependent services.

Anyone know another one? Feel free to add/edit.