# I can't redirect to an app running on a different port after pressing a button

Tags: reactjs, go, nginx, docker-compose

The scenario I would like to achieve is shown in the figure below.

[Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq8xd.png)

Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  frontend:
    container_name: site-a-front-ctn
    image: customized image a
    volumes:
      - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - docker-network

  backend:
    container_name: site-a-back-ctn
    image: customized image ab
    ports:
      - 5601
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - docker-network

  siteb:
    container_name: site-b-ctn
    image: customized image b
    ports:
      - 3002
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - docker-network

networks:
  docker-network:
    external: true
```

Site A is built with React and has a button on it.

When the button is pressed, it calls "/com/redirect" on the backend of site A.

"/com/redirect" is coded in Gin framework as follows.

```
import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func UpdateRedirect(c *gin.Context) {
    c.Redirect(http.StatusMovedPermanently, "http://site-b-ctn:3002")
}
```

And the configuration of nginx mounted on the front-end container of site A is as follows.
conf.d/default.conf:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name localhost;
    
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }

    location = /com/redirect {
        proxy_pass http://site-b-ctn:3002/;
        
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, Authorization, Accept";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
        
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_hide_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin';
    }
        
    location /com/ {
        proxy_pass http://site-a-back-ctn:5601/com/;
        
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, Authorization, Accept";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
        
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_hide_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin';
    }
}
```

By the way, site b is also implemented in the Gin framework.

main.go:

```
func main() {
  :
  :
  router := gin.Default()
  router.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
      AbortOnError:         false,
      AllowAllOrigins:      false,
      AllowedOrigins: []string{
          "http://localhost",
          "http://localhost/",
          "http://localhost/*",
          "http://localhost:3002",
          "http://localhost:3002/*",
          "http://127.0.0.1",
          "http://127.0.0.1/*",
          "http://127.0.0.1:3002",
          "http://127.0.0.1:3002/*",
          "http://127.0.0.1/:1",
          "http://::1",
      },
      AllowedMethods: []string{
          "POST",
          "GET",
          "OPTIONS",
      },
      AllowedHeaders: []string{
          "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
          "Content-Type",
          "Content-Length",
          "Accept-Encoding",
          "Authorization",
          "X-CSRF-Token",
          "Authorization",
      },
      ExposedHeaders:   []string{},
      AllowCredentials: true,
      MaxAge:   12 * time.Hour,
  }), static.Serve("/", static.LocalFile(".frontend/build", true)))
  :
  :
  router.Run(":3002")
}
```

Under the above conditions, pressing the redirect button returns the status code 200, but there is no change on the screen.

I am not sure if it is a problem with the proxy settings or the implementation of "/com/redirect".

Can anyone give me a hint on how to solve this?

Comment: "it calls `/com/redirect`" - how? (making an AJAX call will not change the page unless you do something with the response). I'm also a bit confused; you redirect to `http://site-b-ctn:3002` but there does not appear to be anything listening on the port. I suspect your intention may be to [reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847771/configure-nginx-with-proxy-pass) using nginx, but that would be on port 80 and you have not configured nginx for this. You also have a number of references to `localhost` that need to be updated to your domain names (e.g. `server_name localhost;`).

Comment: /com/redirect" is called by Axios.
Specifically, ```axios.get("/com/updateRedirect", { headers: requestHeaders }).then((res) => {
      console.log("Redirecting...") ;
    });```
The redirect destination "http://site-b-ctn:3002" is being listened to by Gin. ```router.Run(":3002")```

Comment: "being listened to by Gin" - correct but Gin is running within a container which you have exposed via an [ephemeral port](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports) (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69233126/11810946)). This means that anything not on the internal docker network will be unable to reach it on port 3002 (and, based upon your diagram the client is external).

Comment: I understand about ephemeral port.
However, the redirection to port 3002 is from another app (site A) in the same docker-network, so i think the communication should be working. (To be precise, the backend of site A is handling the redirection).
I have now prepared another Apache proxy container and configured it as follows, but it did not work.

`ProxyPass /com/update http://site-b-ctn:3002/
ProxyPassReverse /com/update http://site-b-ctn:3002/`

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood how an [http redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) works. Your go app will respond with status code `301` ([StatusMovedPermanently](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#pkg-constants)) with the url; the browser will then request that url (which it will not find).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.
I had completely misunderstood.
Was what I am trying to do not feasible in the first place?
I am already tired....

Comment: It's feasible but I'd suggest doing what I thought your diagram showed; reverse proxy through `nginx` (or another tool like [traefik](https://traefik.io/traefik/)/[caddy](https://github.com/caddyserver/caddy)). You can configure these tools to direct traffic based on lots of factors (requested domain is relevant in your case) and they can handle SSL termination which keeps things simple. This can also avoid CORS issues (e.g. serve html on `http://blah.com` and your API on `http://blah.com/api` even if these are provided by different apps). As above check use of `localhost` in configs.

Comment: I would like to try traefik/caddy. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `nginx` is a pretty good reverse proxy too (probably the most used in the world!). Personally I use Traefik but that is mainly because I waned something written in Go.